# Troubleshooting Roland analog synthesizer's 'moving' dead notes

Tags: instruments, maintenance, synthesizer, electronics, repair

I have a 1982 [Roland Juno-60](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roland_Juno-60) 'polyphonic' analog synthesizer.

[image]

Starting about 6 months ago it began having 'moving' dead notes.

What I mean by that, is that there is no evidence that any *one* key is 'dying' (or really evidence that *any* key is dying for that matter). The electronics overall usually seem ok.

What happens instead is that every 6th unique note that I play (or sometimes 4th or 5th) creates no sound. It comes across as being 'dead.' I can hit that note 500 times and it still will not produce a note. However, as long as I hit another 6 unique notes, that original dead key works again while my new 6th note no longer produces any sound when pressed.

This occurs in any pre-set voicing or even after heavy modification of the knobs/sliders. There is an arpeggiator button (auto arpeggiates all notes being pressed) that *sometimes* will force the 'dead' note back, but this has been very inconsistent.

**My questions: What is causing this mysterious 'moving' dead note??** And **How can I fix it??**

I assume it's got something to do with some malfunction in sound wave production (vs. a strictly physical/electronic malfunction). But I really have no idea.

Any thoughts or expertise anyone can share would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it's anything like the archetypal polyphonic analog synthesizer (the Prophet 5), it has six analog voices (probably consisting of two oscillators, a low pass filter, and a couple envelopes each, and maybe more). Those six voices are not triggered directly by the keyboard. Instead, there's a microprocessor that allocates key presses to voices in a rotating fashion.

If one of your voices is dead, then every sixth key press (**or so**) would not make a sound. The "or so" is important. The algorithm in the microprocessor might not always go in precisely round robin order, depending on things like holding down a sustain pedal or certain envelope settings.

So, sadly, that's my guess - you have a dead analog voice. It's possible each voice is on its own PCB or daughter card so maybe replacing the card would fix it and be relatively easy.

Comment: This sounds right. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roland_Juno-60) confirms that the Juno-60 is in fact a 6-voice polysynth. As for searching for solutions, are "analog voice" and "PCB" the best search terms, or would you recommend other terms to help me on my way?

Comment: Initial searches for "dead analog voice in Juno-60" took me to the following relevant sites:  [here](http://www.vintagesynth.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=41035),  [here](http://www.retrosound.de/junoservice.htm), and [here](https://www.gearslutz.com/board/electronic-music-instruments-electronic-music-production/432208-dead-voice-chip-maybe.html)

Comment: There's also apparently a [Yahoo Group](https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/Roland_Junos/info) dedicated to Roland Juno owners. It appears to have been active from 2000 - 2015, but who know, perhaps folks are still watching it...